# Predefined Literals for .snippets

Tags: visual-studio, code-snippets

I am creating a few snippets and have found that there are a couple pre defined literals that can be used, such as `$selected$` and `$end$`. `$selected$` is the selected text when the snippet is inserted. `$end$` is where the cursor will be when the snippet is inserted.

Are there any other pre-defined literals that can be used as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171435.aspx) it mentions only those two you've said - `$selected$` and `$end$`. So probably that's all.

> Literals and objects cannot contain an ID element with a value of selected or end. The value `$selected$` represents text selected in the document that is to be inserted into the snippet when it is invoked. `$end$` marks the location to place the cursor after the code snippet is inserted.